# Warming Zone on Stove on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul, appliances

A stove is a gas stove but has both an electric warming drawer as well as an electric "warming zone" surface.   The warming zone is in the middle of the stove - sort of a glass top - and can be set with a manual knob.   When turned on, it is a hot surface (like a hot plate), but not hot enough to cook

The question is whether this can be used on Shabbat in the same way as a hot plate to keep a pot warm.

Comment: 1) We do not know anything about how your "warming zone" works so how can we respond. 2) Site rules are that "Questions that appear to be requests for personal practical advice will be either edited to more general wording or closed." ...... So invite your Rabbi to view the zone and ask him for a response.

Comment: How can anyone answer this without seeing your stove? You'd have to at least edit in a more detailed description of the device to make this question workable for our site.

Comment: The manual knob change the temperature? (Maybe first ask if a hot plate with a knob changes the law)

Comment: I think I get the idea of the warming zone, as my GE Profile oven has one. It's in the middle of the top of the range between the burners. Offhand, sounds like it may work similar to a blech. Not sure. Regardless, even if you were allowed to use it, to me, it sounds unsafe to leave it on all night. I can't tell you how many accidents / tragedies have happened with hot plates and hot zones!

Comment: can you add in information about the oven itself? Make and model number, perhaps a link to the oven online? . Then you can generalize the question to something like "the ___ oven is a gas oven with an electric heating area. Can one use that on Shabbos?"

Comment: Aaron, welcome to Mi Yodeya. Thanks for this first question, I hope you will get good answers. If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Comment: Suggestion - Check the Star K web site. There are a few stoves that they certify for Shabbat use, or they tend to write articles that address these technological questions. You may find something, there.